# How to improve spam protection using postfix?

Tags: postfix, spam, spamassassin

I try to improve the spam protection of my postfix install for several weeks now, but I still receive spam.

What I've done so far:

- Added SpamAssassin
- Added SPF record
- Tuned rejection rules

Now I'm stuck and have no clue what else I could do. Please help!
Here's my postconf -n output - any ideas?

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[localhost]:10024
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = mandelkind.email
mynetworks = 83.150.63.0/28 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org, reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org, reject_rbl_client dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/email.mandelkind/www.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/email.mandelkind/www.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Add postgrey, even the shortest delay can help,  I use 6 seconds.

Past that check your headers,  see where spam is originating,  build a bayesian filter, honeypot, open source will only go so far.